# "JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file" : Unable to install Joomla templates

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla3.0

While trying to install `Joomla` Templates I get this error :

```
Warning

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file
```

What file is it ?

I am using *Joomla 3* . I downloaded few of the Joomla templates from torrent and all of these show up this error. What is it ? It can be so for the all the templates I downloaded.Is it that Joomla 1.5 template won't work with Joomla 3 ?

How do I install these templates ? I see a file named `templateDetails.xml` in there.

*Note:*

Here is the `templateDetails.xml` : [thexml.html](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/Samples/blob/master/thexml.html)

Comment: can you provide the code from your **templateDetails.xml** please?

Comment: @Lodder [thexml.html](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/Samples.git) which is basically `templateDetails.xml`

Comment: the link you have provided is to a github page with a Java project

Comment: @Lodder did you see **thexml.html** I mentioned in the comment ?

Comment: @Lodder Is there anything wrong with the code ?

Comment: the link you wrote above doesn't show me an XML file

Comment: @Lodder [Don't you see this file](http://i47.tinypic.com/np2n39.jpg) in the [link](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/Samples.git) I gave ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Unsure why you were not using the direct link to the file on Github instead of just pointing to the Github account, updated that link

Comment: @Lodder are you able to migrate Joomla-based questions to JSE or do the moderators here have to do it?

Comment: @mickmackusa a moderator here has to do it ;)

Answer (score 8):

I found something while browsing.

Just change the .xml file in the template folder.

change the 'install' tag to 'extension' and change the version to 2.5 or higher... and it worked for me.

The step by step process is explained in the below link

<s>http://www.techaviyal.com/jinstaller-install-cannot-find-joomla-xml-setup-file-joomla/</s> (deadlink)

Answer (score 1):

Is it that Joomla 1.5 template won't work with Joomla 3 ?
The answer is **YES** ,You cannot use Joomla 1.5 Templates directly to Joomla 3. Because from Joomla 1.6 the structure of the Installer file has been changed. You need to upgrade you Joomla 1.5 template to Newer version of Joomla.To do this see the link below:

[Upgrading a Joomla 1.5 template to Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_template_to_Joomla_2.5)

[Developing a Basic Template](http://docs.joomla.org/User%3aRvsjoen/tutorial/Developing_a_Template/Part_01)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, didn't even see the xml file at first.

Ok the XML file was for a Joomla 1.5 template and thus won't work.

I have updated it so that it will now work for Joomla 3

http://pastebin.com/1Dv6g6ip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0" type="template" method="upgrade">
        <name>themza_j15_11</name>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <creationDate>2008-10-20</creationDate>
        <author>Themza Team</author>
        <authorEmail>templates@themza.com</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>http://www.themza.com</authorUrl>
        <copyright>ThemZa 2008</copyright>
        <license>ThemZa TOS</license>
        <description>Computer Society</description>
        <files>
                <filename>index.php</filename>
                <filename>index.html</filename>
                <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
                <filename>template_thumbnail.png</filename>
                <filename>params.ini</filename>
                <filename>favicon.ico</filename>
                <filename>component.php</filename>
                <folder>css</folder>
                <folder>html</folder>
                <folder>images</folder>
        </files>
        <positions>
                <position>breadcrumb</position>
                <position>left</position>
                <position>right</position>
                <position>top</position>
                <position>user1</position>
                <position>user2</position>
                <position>user3</position>
                <position>user4</position>
                <position>debug</position>
                <position>syndicate</position>
        </positions>
        <config>
                <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="basic">
                        <field name="pageAlignment" type="radio" default="center" label="Page Alignment" description="Page Alignment">
                        <option value="left">left</option>
                        <option value="center">center</option>
                        <option value="right">right</option>
                </field>
                <field type="spacer" />
                <field name="colorVariation" type="list" default="red" label="Color Variation" description="Color variation to use">
                        <option value="red">Red</option>
                        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                        <option value="green">Green</option>
                        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                </field>
                <field type="spacer" />
                <field name="hideLogo" type="radio" default="0" label="Hide Logo" description="Hide the logo.">
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                </field>
                <field type="spacer" />
                <field name="hideBannerArea" type="radio" default="0" label="Hide Banner Area" description="Hide the banner section under the menu.">
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                </field>
                <field type="spacer" />
                <field name="dateDisplay" type="radio" default="1" label="Date Display" description="Display the date in the top right corner of the template.">
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                </field>

                </fieldset>
                </fields>
        </config>
</extension>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For JOOMLA 3.0

It is so simple unzip mod_as_scroller.zip then in mod_as_scroller folder find the joomla 3.0 folder and install as_scroller.zip it is done no more errors

Answer (score 0):

I modified my module by these links below:

https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module#Creating_mod_helloworld.xml