# Component install in Joomal2.5 - JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I am newbie to Joomla! I am trying to install simple hello world component into my local site by referring [this site](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component#admin.2Fsql.2Fupdates.2Fmysql.2F0.0.1.sql).

But the warning is coming as below:

```
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file
Copy failed
JInstaller: :Install: Failed to copy file /var/www/newsite/tmp/install_52832b764aa08/com_helloworld-1.6-part01 (1)/site/index.html to /var/www/newsite/components/com_helloworld/index.html
```

I have referred the other questions posted in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321329/jinstaller-install-cannot-find-joomla-xml-setup-file-unable-to-install-jo) too

In that, the answer was like that to change the version and  tag to . But, the code which i am having, contains the same only.

Then what was the problem?

Did I miss something, while trying to install this component?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file (on line 2), seeing as you're using Joomla 2.5, ensure that it says `version="2.5"`. Once done, in the Joomla backend go to **System Information** then **Directory Permissions** and ensure all the folders are writable. If you see some are not writable, you will need to change the permissions for them. Folders need to be set to *755* and files should be *644*.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had changed the version as 2.5. configuration.php file only was not having writable permission. Now i changed that. still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: did you compile the hello world component on your own from the docs or did you download the package that they provide? You could always use a component generator such as [this](http://joomlacomponentcreator.codelydia.com)

Comment: I have download the package that they provided. Then also, i have to use the website which u referred?

Comment: How did hello world component compile on own? Shall you refer any link for that? I don't have any idea on that.

Comment: What I mean by "compile it on your own" is did you copy the code from the Joomla documentation and create the files manually? You don't have to use the link I provided but I would recommend using a component generator as it will give you a good head start :)